# How to get PID with only app name

Tags: bash

When I run `ps aux` on my computer, I get output like this

```
myname   234   0.0  0.9   828060  76584   ??  S     9:10am   0:27.01 /RandomApp.app
```

If I pipe the output to grep, I can look for the name of a particular app

```
ps aux | grep "/RandomApp.app/"
```

Is there anyway from there to get the `PID` (the value in the second column) of the result of the `grep`.

Comment: `pgrep -f RandomApp.app` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps aux | awk '/RandomApp.app/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't get it to work. for example, I try this and it's just hanging at the command line `ps aux | awk ‘/usr/libexec/xpcd {print $2}'` The full path is `/usr/libexec/xpcd`.

Comment: Make sure the full path shows up on a `ps aux`. Also, your are dealing with regex, so the `/` char has a special meaning (the string matched must be between `//`, like `/string/`) so you must escape the `/` if you want it to match. To awk that string, you should write instead `ps aux | awk ‘/\/usr\/libexec\/xpcd/ {print $2}'`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that in the `command` column for `ps aux` it only shows a limited number of characters, so sometimes I can't get the whole path. For example, for my dropbox app, it only shows `/Applications/Dropbox.app/Conte` (even if I widen the terminal). Therefore, I need to be able to do a text search.

Comment: thanks, I understand the escapes however it hangs running this `ps aux | awk ‘/\/usr\/libexec\/xpcd/ {print $2}'`

Comment: Depends on your system, but it could be a "feature" to show a "clean" process list. Do a `ps aux | grep .` and check if full command is printed. If so, awk will also see the full path and arguments passed. Also, some others suggested `pgrep`, check it.

Comment: Sorry, first quote was wrong, `ps aux | awk '/\/usr\/libexec\/xpcd/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
ps ax -o pid,comm | grep "/RandomApp.app" | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

Or take a look at `pgrep`:

```
pgrep bash
```

Output (e.g.):

```
3006
3440
10714
16524
16603
16863
18921
23945
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match` operator. If `RandomApp.app` is in the 11th column, this code will print the second column.

```
$11 ~ /RandomApp.app/ { print $2 }
```

Put the above in a file `aboveawkfile.awk` and run with `-f` operator. so

```
ps aux | awk -f aboveawkfile.awk
```